# scrape_tracker doen't give any alert with libtorrent

Tags: c++, libtorrent

I'm using libtorrent in a C++ application I'm building, and downloads work perfectly, but I would like to ask the tracker the number of seeds and peers it has connected before trying to start the download.

I tried with scrape_tracker(), but I never receive alerts. I think I don't use alerts the right way, but I don't find code I can use.
This is what I do:

```
while (running)
{
   sleep(1000);

   std::vector<alert*> alerts;
    s.pop_alerts(&alerts);

   for (std::vector<alert*>::iterator i = alerts.begin(), end(alerts.end()); i != end; ++i)
   {
       scrape_failed_alert* tpf = alert_cast<scrape_failed_alert>(*i);
       if (tpf)
           MessageBox(0,"alert",0,0);

       scrape_reply_alert* tpr = alert_cast<scrape_reply_alert>(*i);
       if (tpr)
           MessageBox(0,"alert",0,0);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [mask](http://libtorrent.org/reference-Session.html#set_alert_mask()) that enables and disables categories of alerts to be posted. (some categories can be quite verbose). By default, only errors are posted as well as responses to specific calls (like save resume data, add torrent etc.)

It turns out that the scrape request is only posted when the `alert::tracker_notification` category of alerts is enabled. This is most likely an oversight, since scrape alerts are only posted in response to an active call to perform a scrape, the response should be posted regardless of the alert mask.

However, if you enable tracker notification alerts, I imagine you'll get the scrape response.

```
s.set_alert_mask(alert::tracker_notification | alert::error_notification);
```

Comment: You got it ! I receive only "missing or invalid 'hash' entry" but at least I have a reply. Thanks